# Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Core.dll

Tags: windows, azure, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to execute a job for HDInsight.
THe following is the get certificate code, and its throwing an exception in

```
X509Certificate2 cert= store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().First(item => item.FriendlyName == certFriendlyName);"

// Get the certificate object from certificate store using the friendly name to identify it

 X509Store store = new X509Store();
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 X509Certificate2 cert=   store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2().
 First(item => item.FriendlyName == certFriendlyName);
 JobSubmissionCertificateCredential creds =new JobSubmissionCertificateCredential (new Guid(subscriptionID), cert, clusterName);
```

I have used the following namespaces:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight;
using Microsoft.Hadoop.Client;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: It keeps on throwing an exception, I could not find any solution to on msdn except for some similar posts where the solution was using System.Linq, which i have already used here.

Answer (score 0):

What's the exception you are getting?

This code is using the current user store, is your cert in current user store?

I would recommend you to first list all the certs friendlynames to validate if it exists.